# Getting values from other db tables using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables in my database , where the first database ( Table1) has `Groupid, Values, Category` as columns. In my other database, having the `Groupid` again and for this database, I need to get the data according to `Table1's category,` which is something like below:

If Category ( in `Table 1` ) == `SAVINGS OR == ONLINE --- get data from Tax papers`

If Category ( `in Table 1` ) != `SAVINGS  AND != ONLINE  --- get data from CHEQUE papers`

I need help in PHp code syntax to get the details for my `table 2`

Please note I've a database table where the tax paper and cheque papers details are aleady stored.

Kindly somebody help me on PHP code syntax for this scenario

Thanks,

Comment: You need SQL Joins, not PHP code for this.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two tables in one database or are you actually using two databases?

Comment: Learn about SQL JOIN.

Comment: in case of two databases, you need to learn about the GRANT command in mysql (to allow your db user to access and use the second database). After that, JOIN is your fiend, again from mysql

Comment: I mean two tables in one database. Thanks

Comment: I am writing php code for a project where i need to take the details from one table and insert into another table based on few conditions. Hope i clarified. Thanks

Comment: The issue got solved , thanks